# Why does prototype need to be accessed via instance?

Tags: javascript, class, instance, function-prototypes

I'm trying to create a class constant, but I guess my novice-level understanding of JavaScript is showing. When this code executes:

```
var Class = function() {};
Class.prototype = { CONST : 1 };
var instance = new Class(),
c1 = instance.CONST,
c2 = Class.CONST;
```

the result is that `c1 === 1` and `c2 === undefined`. Why isn't `c2 === 1`? Doesn't JavaScript look up the prototype chain for `Class`?

Comment: I'm not confident enough to put this in an answer, but I'd say that Class doesn't have a prototype chain... it's a constructor. An object that is an instance of Class has the prototype chain that you created with `Class.prototype = ...`. In other words, `Class.prototype` does not refer to the prototype chain for the `Class` object but to the prototype chain for objects created by the `Class` constructor.

Comment: @LarsH - I'm pretty sure that function objects have prototype chains. The second part of your comment, though, clarifies things a lot. I was mixing up the `prototype` property of `Class` with the prototype chain.

Comment: Ted, I don't deny that function objects have prototype chains... just that A.prototype is the prototype chain for object A. (I'm agreeing with you.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you trying to do is what would be called a class static method in other language.
To do that in Javascript you have to write

`Class.CONST = 1;`  then you can call it with `Class.CONST;`

if you try to access it with instance method like `new Class().CONST`, it would be undefined

Back to your question, everything in Class.prototype is only accessible to an instance of the object(ie, created via `new`), not Class itself. Why?

Consider the implementation of `new`

```
Function.method('new', function () {
    var that = Object.create(this.prototype);
    var other = this.apply(that, arguments);
    return (typeof other === 'object' && other) || that;
});
```

first `Object.create(this.prototype)` create a brand new object which inherited from `this.prototype` which u declared via `Class.prototype = { Const : 1 }`, then it call `this.apply(that, arguments)`, which just call your declared Class function using `that` as the `this` variable. then it return the object. You can see that the Class function is simply used as a way to stuff things into the newly born object create via `new`. and only the object created has access to the prototype methods.

Comment: Okay. That's what was confusing me. I was under the (apparently mistaken) impression that assigning to `Class.prototype` was setting the prototype for `Class`. So if I have it right, the `prototype` key has special meaning when set on a constructor function, but it has nothing to do with the prototype chain for the constructor function itself; it's just used to set up the prototype chain for instances. Do I have it right now? (P.S., couldn't you simply set `Class.CONST = 1`--rather than to a function that returns 1--to get a "class constant"?)

Comment: yes, javascript will only look up the prototype chain of a object created via Object.create(), new is just a syntactic sugar for java programmers.  
Class.CONST = 1 is fine, Class.Anything just append Anything to Class object

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to access the `CONST` property of a constructor (`Class = function(){}`). `CONST` won't be available until you instantiate `Class`.

A couple of good links about this:

- [MDN - Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_constructor_prototype)
- [MDN - Inheritance Revisited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited)
- [JavaScript Constructors, Prototypes, and the `new` keyword](http://pivotallabs.com/users/pjaros/blog/articles/1368-javascript-constructors-prototypes-and-the-new-keyword)

Comment: That last link was very helpful. It makes clear that the `prototype` property for a constructor function has nothing to do with the prototype chain for the function. That little detail seems to be missing from the MDN documents (which I had read before posting the question).

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that instances inherit from their constructor's public prototype, so `c1` has a `CONST` property inherited from from `Class.prototype` (strictly, it's the instance's private `[[Prototype]]` property).

On the other hand, `Class` is an instance of `Function`, so it inherits from `Function.prototype` (i.e. its private `[[Prototype]]` is `Function.prototype`), not `Class.prototype`, so it doesn't have a `CONST` property.

The value of an object's `[[Prototype]]` is set when it's constructed and can never be changed. Replacing `Class.prototype` with some other object will only affect new instances.

Note that in some older Mozilla browsers (such as Firefox) there was a [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) property that referenced an object's `[[Prototype]]` and could be set, but that is now deprecated.

Generally it's best not to talk in terms of classes in regard to javascript, since it infers behaviour and features that can only be emulated to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

`Class` is a function object. Function objects don't have a `CONST` property. It's used to construct a 'Class' object. 'Class' objects are custom objects which have a `CONST` property because it's declared in the constructor.